# permalink repeated

Tags: permalinks

I just moved my blog to a new server (I've updated the dns).

Everything is fine except the permalink settings. I used to choose the day-name style like: `mydomain.com/blog/2013/08/28/sample-post/`. But after the moving, it turns something like: `mydomain.com/blog/blog/2013/08/28/sample-post/`.

So if I keep using this style, my previous blogs can't be visited because their links lead to `mydomain.com/blog/blog/2012/09/12/something`, while they should be `mydomain.com/blog/2012/09/12/something.`

If I switch it to the default: `mydoamin.com/blog/?p=123`, all my old posts can be visited.

Any one have dealt with this problem?

Comment: What is the code that generates the permalinks?

Comment: I just click the button in wordpress dashboard

Comment: What are the settings at wp-admin -> Settings -> General for the two URL values-- third and fourth from the top?

Comment: Em...I guess you're referring to the home and site url, right? That's the weird thing here: they just don't exist. It really sucks to be the site admin after someone created it.

Comment: You are not an admin? Are the home and site urls `define`d in `wp-config.php`?

Comment: yes
define('WP_HOME','http://mydomain.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mydomain.com/blog/');
but they don't look so in the wp netadmin dashboard
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/blog/');

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are multisite which I don't use but if this were a single site install I would tell you to remove `blog/` from `WP_SITEURL`.